# How do I get back my Helmsman's Recourse after throwing it?

Tags: magic-items, pathfinder-2e, ranged-attack

[Helmsman's Recourse](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=1858) is a *specific* shield from Treasure Vault, that is based on a [Meteor Shield](https://2e.aonprd.com/Shields.aspx?ID=13). The only benefit of a Meteor Shield over a Steel Shield (that I can see) is that it can be *thrown* to 30 feet.

The [Returning](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=301) *property* rune solves this problem of thrown weapons, but Helmsman's Recourse is a specific item, so only fundamental runes can be added to it, not *property* runes.

**So if I throw my Helmsman's Recourse, how do I get it back?**

Going there and picking it up *is* an option, I am looking for something more efficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## You *can* add a Returning rune to it

You just have to add a [Shield Spike](https://2e.aonprd.com/Weapons.aspx?ID=42) or a [Shield Boss](https://2e.aonprd.com/Weapons.aspx?ID=41) to the shield first, then this attachment can have both property and fundamental runes.

There are some other (in my opinion, weaker) options:

### [Ricochet Stance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1726)

It is a feat for 8th level Rogues or 6th level Fighters. While in this stance, and not throwing further than the first range increment, the shield returns back to you after a throw.

### [Returning Throw](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1403)

This Dwarf feat is worse than the above, *and* of higher level, but at least it uses an ancestry feat.

Comment: You should include the [Shield Throw](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=490) trait in the first part of your answer since it's questionable whether you could put Returning on the (non-thrown) shield spike or boss.

Comment: Not worth a separate answer,  but the way this question is written, you probably should add "go there and pick it up" to the list.

Comment: @Mołot, question edited